# Passing outputId into ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, plotly

I've just started at an internship where my first task is to improve a Shiny application by updating all existing ggplot graphs into Plotly graphs. I'm pretty new to R and Shiny, so I'm having a couple of issues getting started.

Currently, one of the graphs in this application are generated as follows:

```
    output$barBoxPlot <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("Barplot", width = 700, height = 300
                 , click = "plot_click"
                 , hover = "plot_hover"
                 , brush = "plot_brush")
    })
```

Where "Barplot" is an outputId that corresponds to a ggplot graph generated in another part of the code.

I'm trying to plot this graph ("Barplot") as a Plotly graph, using the ggplotly() function, using something like this:

```
output$barBoxPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(<insert graph here>)
})
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pass in the "Barplot" parameter (which is an outputId) into ggplotly(). ggplotly takes in an instance of a ggplot graph, and not an outputId.

Is there any way to pass in an outputId into ggplotly()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would've put this in a comment but can't to that yet because of reputation:

There are multiple ways to solve this wihtout trying to pass an `outputID` to `ggplotly()`.

1. In the `reactive` that is in the `output$Barplot <- renderPlot(this_reactive_here())` , use `ggplotly()` directly (if you don't need the original `output$barBoxPlot`
2. Create a function or a reactive that takes a `ggplot` object and only does `return(ggplotly(x))` , then put that into your `renderPlotly()`

*EDIT for clarification on 2:*

The `Barplot` that is in `plotOutput` should have a server entry that looks something like this:

```
output$Barplot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data, aes(...)) # etc
})
```

Take the code inside and put it in a reactive, like this:

```
barplot_ggplot <- reactive({
  ggplot(data, aes(...)) # etc
})
```

Then you can use it in the `output$Barplot` as `barplot_ggplot()` and in the `renderPlotly()` as `ggplotly(barplot_ggplot())`.

I hope that's a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm still confused about how exactly to do the second of your suggestions? My issue is how to access the ggplot object - do I pass output$Barplot into this new function/reactive, and pass the returned object into renderPlotly()?

Comment: I should also mention that I do indeed need the original output$barBoxPlot, which is why your first suggestion doesn't necessarily work for me @bendae.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely clearer! I'll give it a shot once I'm back home, and let you know if it works! Thank you :)

Comment: One quick follow-up - how does one go about using barplot_ggplot() in output$Barplot? I understand using barplot_ggplot() in the renderPlotly in output$barBoxPlot, but I'm not sure about the first part.

Comment: `output$Barplot <- renderPlot({ barplot_ggplot() })` and `output$barBoxPlot <- renderPlotly({ ggplotly(barplot_ggplot() })`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I've been trying it out, and it looks like it might work! There is still one kink I have to iron out - currently, barplot_ggplot() is getting called inside a separate section of code from my output$barBoxPlot function, so I have to fix that - but thank you so much @bendae!

Comment: you're welcome! please mark the answer as accepted once you're sure that it solved your problem :)

Comment: Will do! Still trying to figure out how to be able to call barplot_ggplot() inside my output$barBoxPlot (it says the function is not found), but once I get it all together, I'll let you know! Thank you for the help - I'm pretty new to all this, so this was super helpful :)